# Pointwise convergence of $h_n(x) = x^{1+\frac{1}{2n-1}}$

Tags: real-analysis

Okay, maybe I'm missing something obvious but consider $h_n(x) = x^{ 1+ \frac{1}{2n-1}}$ on the set $[-1,1]$. Now consider a fixed $x \in [-1,1]$, we have:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} h_n(x) = x \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x^\frac{1}{2n-1} = x$$

But my book says it's $|x|$? Why?

Comment: Perhaps you could convince yourself by writing $$h_n(x) = x^{2n/(2n-1)}.$$

Comment: Thanks, where was my mistake though?

Comment: What is $\lim_{n\to\infty} (-1)^{1/(2n-1)}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
x^{1+\tfrac{1}{2\,n-1}}=x^{\tfrac{2\,n}{2\,n-1}}=\sqrt[2n+1]{x^{2n}}.
$$
Since $2\,n$ is even, $x^{2n}>0$ if $x\ne0$.

Answer (score 0):

> $x^{1+\tfrac{1}{2\,n-1}}=x^{\tfrac{2\,n}{2\,n-1}} = x^{2{\frac{1}{2-\frac{1}{n}}}}\to \sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ as $n\to \infty$

Comment: Thanks. But why can't you go the other way? I.e., $x^{2\frac{1}{2-\frac{1}{n}}} = \left(x^{\frac{1}{2-\frac{1}{n}}}\right)^{2} \rightarrow (\sqrt{x})^2 = x$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: this won't make sense if $x<0$